# What's the meaning of "I" in "All those in favor say I" in this Friends episode?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I'm watching [this clip](https://youtu.be/8wewPn7TZfs?t=59) of *Friends* in which everybody was making fun of Rachel when they found Rachel would freak out when something comes close enough to the eyeball.

Monica said "Me, Myself, and I?"; Chandler said "How much did I love The King and I?" The word "I" makes sense in both contexts, but what Ross said seems to be:

> Hey, does anybody want to get some lunch? All those in favor say I?

I don't understand how the word "I" fits in this context. I looked up the word "favor" in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/favor) and I see there are a few "in favor" expressions:

- **be in favor of sth/doing sth**: to support or approve of something
- **in your favor**: When something is in your favor, it gives you an advantage
- **find in sb's favor**: If a judge finds in someone's favor, he or she says that that person is not guilty.

Although I can understand each expressions separately, none of them seems to make sense in Ross's context of "lunch". **Could someone explain the use of "I" in Ross's line and why "I" is appropriate there?**

Comment: Did you hear it or see it written? If written, it is a typical mistake for an automated system. AKA a voice vote. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_vote

Comment: @Lambie See it written [here](https://uncutfriendsepisodes.tripod.com/season5/522uncut.htm) which seems to be transcribed by a native speaker (but I'm not sure). YouTube's CC says "eye" which doesn't make much sense, either.

Comment: Yes, well, thanks. It is in any case a transcription error.

Comment: I can easily see how even a native Anglophone not familiar with ***Ay[e] = Yes*** (dated / archaic, dialectal) might think ***Say I*** here is shortened from *Say "**I am** [in favour]."*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word you are asking about is **aye**.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aye) provides this definition:

> **Definition of aye (Entry 1 of 3)**
> : YES
> *aye, aye, sir*

Wiktionary adds this:

> **aye aye, sir**
> *(idiomatic, nautical) The correct and seamanlike reply, onboard a Royal Navy (or US Navy) ship, on receipt of an order from someone of senior rank or authority. It means "I understand the command and hasten to comply with the order."*

This sense is commonly used in English-speaking navies and films about space ships. It is also common among inhabitants of northern Britain. The character [Chief Engineer Lt. Commander Scott](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotty_(Star_Trek)) on *Star Trek* frequently said **aye** or **aye, Captain** when responding affirmatively to questions. This was intended to reflect both the naval influence and his Scottish ancestry.

Variations on **aye aye, sir** are often used humorously in friendly conversation.

The following is another Merriam-Webster definition:

> **Definition of aye (Entry 2 of 3)**
> : an affirmative vote or voter
> *the ayes have it*

This usage is common in the British Parliament and in the United States Senate and House of Representatives when matters are put to a voice vote. Ross is using **aye** this way, and he uses **favor** in the first sense that you have provided. The chairperson of a body that follows parliamentary procedure (including committees of many types) will say, **All those in favor say 'aye'** when a proposal is to be voted upon.

It's important to note that Ross is [playing with words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_play). The humor depends on the fact that **aye, eye,** and **I** sound exactly alike.

Comment: In some parts of northern England, the use of "aye" isn't at all humorous but is just part of the local dialect.  It is also used quite seriously in Parliament when voting by voice - this presumably corresponds to entry 1 ("yes") rather than 2, since no one would shout out "affirmative vote", but shouting out "yes" would make a lot of sense.

Comment: Oh, now I totally get it. So Ross was saying "All those (people who would like to get lunch, please) say yes." Because Monica's and Chandler's uses of "I" use the meaning of "I" itself, I thought Ross also used it that way, not to mention I have not learned "aye" yet.

Comment: @rjpond I'm curious why "aye" is used in Parliament but not "yes". Is it just some habit carried on or is there any specific reason behind?

Comment: @yaobin Yes, there's [a lot of history](https://sites.google.com/site/paulmcclintockparliamentarian/history-of-aye-and-no) behind it. The simplest explanation is "because governing bodies, especially the Parliament of Great Britain, set great store by tradition." A more complicated question is how the evolutions of "Aye," Yea," and "Yes" got all tangled up.

Comment: @yaobin I think it is just ancient tradition: they had to pick one of the words, and the word "aye" was then in more widespread and common use than it is now.  Alternatively, perhaps a shouted "aye" is more distinctive or more audible than a shouted "yes".

Comment: The US Senate and House of Representatives also say "Aye" (or "Nay") when a voice vote is called. It's an old tradition, dating to our British roots.

Comment: _All those in favour say 'aye'_ is a traditional expression used in formal debates. They were evidently competing to say phrases with a word that sounds like 'eye'.

Comment: Rules of parliamentary procedure: Robert's Rules of Order.